# Add a mask to the webcam view in the screen

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, frontend

I need to add a webcam picture option to take pictures of documents. However, it's importante that the user take the picture with the document in a specific position. With this in mind, a layout requirement is to add a mask in the webcam picture screen, like the image below:

[image]

Add the webcam picture option is easy, but there is a way to add/draw a mask to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just place a semi transparent div over the top of the canvas that the webcam is rendering to.